# Melhorando visual tabela gerada pelo python com django e bootstrap

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-3

Eu tenho uma tabela que eu gero através do prettytable do python, ela gera uma variavel que contem uma tabela, eu mando essa variavel para o template do django e ela fica toda desconfigurada, teria como eu melhorar o visual dela?
Se nao tiver qual a outra forma de eu gerar essa tabela na tela?

segue meus códigos e imagens da tabela.

```
x = PrettyTable(["Horario", "Ligado", "Desligado"])
    x.align["Horario"] = "2"
    x.align["Ligado"] = "2"
    x.align["Desligado"] = "r"
    x.padding_width = 1
    z=0
    while z < len(teste4):
        x.add_row([teste4[z], tabela1[z], tabela2[z]])
        z = z + 1
    print (x)
```

Gera a tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas na tela quando jogo ela para o tamplate com bootstrap fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando apenas isso de código, acho que ai que esta o erro:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}

Edit


<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token  %}

    <label for="descricao">Data Inicial:</label>
    <input id="descricao" type="text" name="descricao" value="{{ descricao }}" class="form_datetime" /><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({ format: '03/01/19 08:00' });
    </script>
    <label for="descricao2">Data Final:</label>
    <input id="descricao2" type="text" name="descricao2" value="{{ descricao2 }}" class="form_datetime" /><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({ format: '03/01/19 09:00' });
    </script>
    <input type="submit">

    {% if descricao != None %}
    <br><br>
        <p>

            Data Inicial: {{ descricao }}<br>
            Data Final: {{ descricao2 }}<br>
            Tabela: {{ x.get_html_string() }}

        </p>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="{% url 'graficos' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Grafico2</a>
    <a href="{% url 'tela_graficos' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Grafico</a>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Coloca ai a estrutura do seu HTML que recebe os dados, vai ajudar pra te responder

Comment: A forma que o terminal exibe um texto é diferente da forma que o HTML faz isso. Há uma forma de você exibir assim no HTML, mas, como está usando HTML, não seria melhor utilizar a própria `<table>`?

Comment: @hugocsl coloquei todo o código html, sobre o comentario do anderson, ja tentei e ai nao aparece informção alguma